# Redis sorted set leader board ranking on same score

Tags: redis, leaderboard, sortedset

I'm using Redis sorted set to implement the leaderboard of my game, where I show the user ranking in descending order. I'm stuck in a case where two or more users have the same score. So in this case, I want the higher ranking of the user who gets the score first. For example, I'm adding the following entries in Redis.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd testing-key 5 a
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd testing-key 4 b
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd testing-key 5 c
(integer) 1
```

and when I'm querying for the rank in reverse order, I'm getting this

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zrevrange testing-key 0 10
1) "c"
2) "a"
3) "b"
```

but in my case, the ranking should be like

```
1) "a"
2) "c"
3) "b"
```

So is there any provision in Redis to give higher precedence to the entity which entered first in the set with the same score?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found one solution to this problem. In my case, the score is an integer so I converted it into decimal and added `Long.MAX_VALUE - System.nanoTime()` after decimal. So the final score code will be like

```
double finalScore = score.(Long.MAX_VALUE - System.nanoTime());
```

So the final score of the player who scored first would be higher than the second one.  Please let me know if you have any better solution.

Comment: But isn't that what I (perhaps tersely and succinctly, but hopefully not inaccurately and certainly with only the of best intentions intended) answered in my first paragraph?

Comment: Only appending timestamp with score will not produce the desired result if we call `zrevrange`(In my case). Because timestamp field should be descending order to give high ranking to the user who scored first, so the final score should be `mainScore.(Some max value - System.nanoTime())`

Answer (score 13):

If your leaderboard's scores are "small" enough, you may get away with using a combination of the score and the timestamp (e.g. 123.111455234, where 123 is the score). However, since the Sorted Set score is a double floating point, you may lose precision.

Alternatively, keep two Sorted Sets - one with each player's leaderboard score and the other with each player's score timestamp, and use both to determine the order.

Or, use a single sorted set for the leader board, encode the timestamp as part of the member and rely on lexicographical ordering.

Comment: Can you advice the optimal way to do increments of scores and update of timestamps in its decimal part? Thank you for valuable answers.